# Binding update issue in WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a sets of user controls in my WPF application. One of them I've listed in code below:

**RichSlider.xaml** - control directly

```
<UserControl x:Name="RichSliderControl"
         x:Class="CustomControls.RichSlider"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Controls;component/Themes/RichSlider.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

**RichSlider.xaml** - control style

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:CustomControls"
                    >
    <Style x:Key="GlobalLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Century Gothic"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ValueLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlobalLabelStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=RichSliderControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F5F5F5"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSnapToTickEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="{Binding Minimum, ElementName=RichSliderControl}"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="{Binding Maximum, ElementName=RichSliderControl}"/>
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=RichSliderControl}"/>
        <Setter Property="SmallChange" Value="{Binding SmallChange, ElementName=RichSliderControl}"/>
        <Setter Property="LargeChange" Value="{Binding LargeChange, ElementName=RichSliderControl}"/>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=RichSliderControl, Mode=OneWay}"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ValueLabelStyle}"></Label>

            <Slider x:Name="ValueSlider"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                    >
            </Slider>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=RichSliderControl, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
            </Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ValueLabelStyle}"></Label>

            <Slider x:Name="ValueSlider"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    TickPlacement="TopLeft"
                    IsDirectionReversed="True"
                    >
            </Slider>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControls:RichSlider}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSlider}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalSlider}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**RichSlider.xaml.cs** - control code

```
public partial class RichSlider : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(RichSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(RichSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RichSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RichSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallChangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SmallChange", typeof(double), typeof(RichSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LargeChangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LargeChange", typeof(double), typeof(RichSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(RichSlider));

    private static readonly RoutedEvent ValueChangedEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ValueChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>), typeof(RichSlider));

    [Bindable(true)]
    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public double Value
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set
        {
            var val = value;

            if (val < Minimum)
            {
                val = Minimum;
            }

            if (val > Maximum)
            {
                val = Maximum;
            }

            SetValue(ValueProperty, val);
            RaiseEvent(new(ValueChangedEvent));
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public double Minimum
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty);
        set
        {
            var min = value;

            if (Value < min)
            {
                Value = min;
            }

            if (Maximum < min)
            {
                Maximum = min;
            }

            SetValue(MinimumProperty, min);
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public double Maximum
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty);
        set
        {
            var max = value;

            if (Value > max)
            {
                Value = max;
            }

            if (max < Minimum)
            {
                max = Minimum;
            }

            SetValue(MaximumProperty, max);
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public double SmallChange
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(SmallChangeProperty);
        set
        {
            var change = value;

            if (change > LargeChange)
            {
                change = LargeChange;
            }

            SetValue(SmallChangeProperty, change);
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public double LargeChange
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(LargeChangeProperty);
        set
        {
            var change = value;

            if (change < SmallChange)
            {
                change = SmallChange;
            }

            SetValue(LargeChangeProperty, change);
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public Orientation Orientation
    {
        get => (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty);
        set => SetValue(OrientationProperty, value);
    }

    public RichSlider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double> ValueChanged
    {
        add
        {
            AddHandler(ValueChangedEvent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(ValueChangedEvent, value);
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        if (GetTemplateChild("ValueSlider") is Slider slider)
        {
            slider.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(ValueSlider_MouseWheel);
            slider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(ValueSlider_ValueChanged);
        }

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    private void ValueSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new(ValueChangedEvent));
    }

    private void ValueSlider_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var directionReversed = (sender as Slider).IsDirectionReversed;
        
        if (((e.Delta > 0 && !directionReversed) || (e.Delta < 0 && directionReversed)) && Value < Maximum)
        {
            Value++;
        }
        else if (((e.Delta < 0 && !directionReversed) || (e.Delta > 0 && directionReversed)) && Value > Minimum)
        {
            Value--;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok. I'm adding this control to my window.xaml and binding some value like:

```
xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:CustomControls;assembly=Controls"
....
<CustomControls:RichSlider Minimum="1" Maximum="5" SmallChange="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding Path=Acceleration, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{DynamicResource Acceleration}"></CustomControls:RichSlider>
```

And I have a ListBox of items, which contains `Name` and `Acceleration` properties. So, when I'm clicking on ListBoxItem, the value in my `RichSlider` is updating according to the value of `Acceleration` property in item. So, seems like the binding is working ok.
But no. When I'm changing the value in my `RichSlider` manually, the value is no longer updated for all other items and is stuck with the value I set. As evidence:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
```

The `Text` value is updating after selecting another item, not depends from changing I made. I also checked the way like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Acceleration, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
```

and it's also works fine. So, this way I made the conclusion that the issue is in my control, not in Binding, cause for `TextBox` it works, but for `RichSlider` - not.

So, does anyone have any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The setter of a dependency property must not call anything else than SetValue. This is because the setter may be bypassed, and the framework may call SetValue directly, e.g. when a dependency property value is provided by data binding. Implement appropriate PropertyChangedCallbacks or CoercevalueCallbacks.

Comment: Also be aware that directly setting the Value property (e.g by `Value++`) replaces a OneWay Binding of the Value property. A TwoWay Binding would not be replaced, but it might be more appropriate to call `SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, Value + 1);`

Comment: It is also unclear why you not simply derive your control from [RangeBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).